# Win32 API CreateFile to Open File with empty DACL (Security Descriptor)

Tags: winapi, file-permissions, dacl

I'm using CreateFile to get a handle to a file to add ACE to its DACL.
The problem is, when the file has no permissions, I get access denied error when I call the function CreateFile, I'm the OWNER of the file and Admin. 
If I using explorer I can add permissions.

I'm not interested in other functions such as OpenFile or Set security descriptor directly, I'm interested in the right combination to open such files.

I've read in MSDN that I have to use specific access right, I've tried:

CreateFile(lpFileName, READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC, 
0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS);

CreateFile(lpFileName, READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC, 
0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
ACCESS_SYSTEM_SEURITY);

Both I get the access denied.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Gabi

Comment: Minor point but owner doesn't necassarily imply permissions.

Comment: But owner can, even when the file without permissions at all

Answer (score 0):

This should work as the owner is always implicitly granted READ_CONTROL and WRITE_DAC, but I verified the same behavior on my machine.  Out of curiosity I ran Process Monitor on it and found something a bit odd.  When Explorer is opening the file to read the security information, it goes through NtOpenFile(READ_CONTROL).  When my test program which calls CreateFile() is opening the file, it goes through NtCreateFile(READ_CONTROL | **SYNCHRONIZE**).  Obviously this is going to fail as there are no ACEs granting me SYNCHRONIZE access.  I have no idea where this extra access flag is coming from, though.  The only thing I can think of is maybe it has something to do with WOW64 (this is a 32-bit test program running as administrator on a 64-bit machine), but I wasn't motivated enough to research it further.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will test it on different VMs to see if that's the reason.

Comment: Well, I just tried this on 32-bit XP and still saw the same behavior; not sure what to make of it.

Comment: The only reference to this behavior I could find was this (http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Security/AccessControl/FileSecurity@cs/1/FileSecurity@cs).  In any event, GetNamedSecurityInfo() and SetNamedSecurityInfo() will work around this limitation.